# Swift: Making UITableViewCells load from the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to load messages from my UITableView from the bottom up.

[image]

The blue is my UITableView, and the green is my first cell in a tableview with only one cell. The default, and what I have right now, is a normal UITableView where the green cell is at the top of the blue tableview.

I've researched this online, and the best solution I've found is to make several empty clear colored cells, but that doesn't satisfy the programmer in me.

What is the best way to do this?

Update: Yes, with enough cells I can just scroll to the bottom. But I am asking for only a few cells, while maintaining the UITableView's height.

Update 2: Can I create a custom UITableView to implement this? I don't want to change my UITableView into a UICollectionView.

Comment: Create a section header view for section 0 which has a height constraint you can adjust in code. Set the height constraint initially to the height of the table view. When you add new rows, set the height constraint to the table view height minus the number of rows height and reload the section.

Comment: Rather than do a section header, you could also simply set  the table's `tableHeaderView` property to a view you can adjust the height on. If you use a height constraint you can also animate the height change. You can also set this header up in storyboard if that is what you use and CTRL drag the height constraint into your header file, leaving just the code to set its value to be done by hand.